# ASP.NET/MVC i want separate add/update/delete buttons from jqgrid pager mvc5

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid-asp.net

I want to Use JQGrid's pager buttons as my custom buttons for CRUD operation.

[image]

This is different because i want to override buttons click event for other buttons

Comment: Please Anyone answer this question
It's urgent
Otherwise I have to change jqgrid to datagrid

Comment: jq grid what kind of help could you explain briefly

Comment: I want to customize JQgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my own problem

That is I have to get Jqrid's buttons ids
This may not be a totally solid solution since they may change that id naming.

where gridId is my table id for jqgrid

`$('#myDelete').click(function () { $('#del_' + gridId).click(); });
$('#myAdd').click(function () { $('#add_' + gridId).click(); });
$('#myUpdate').click(function () { $('#edit_' + gridId).click(); });`